# how to preview IndexedDB on Safari Mac

Tags: javascript, safari, ionic2

I am currently working on an Ionic2 app. I am using IndexedDB for data storage. I want to view IndexedDB on Safari developer tools.

Is it possible just like in Chrome?

Comment: Yes, in the storage panel of your dev tools you should see *Indexed Database* link. (you may need to click the refresh icon at top right of the panel though)

Answer (score 0):

To view the contents of the IndexedDB you need to hit the refresh button at the top right of the dev tools.

[image]